# Making a nested list appear inline

Tags: html, css

I have the following list:

```
<ul id="inline">
<li><a href="#">One</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Inline1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Inline2</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Two</a>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Inline1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Inline2</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

What i want to show is the first level li as new lines and the nested list to appear at the same height as its parent but inline. Like this:

```
One Inline1 Inline2
Two Inline1 Inline2
```

This is what i have right now:

```
#inline {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

#inline + ul > ul {
  display:inline;
}
```

But I have to basic understanding of css to figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `ul` (child of `#inline`) and the children `li`'s of these `ul`s to `display:inline;`. The *CSS* would be :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/uad4458q/)**

```
#inline ul, #inline ul li {
    display:inline;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple work around for this. Lets see the fiddle.

OLD: http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/sfho4xn8/
Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kiranvarthi/sfho4xn8/2/

```
#inline {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

#inline ul li {
  display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Close but Inline1 and Inline2 should be on the same line as there parent.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS to make it work

```
#inline {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

#inline ul {
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
  margin-left:-30px;
}

#inline ul li {
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
  text-decoration:none;
  margin-left:0px;
}
```